# How to determine whether or not $S_{n}$ contains a subgroup of order $m$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm currently going through group theory practice problems and I needed some assistance with the following exercise:

*Does $S_{9}$ have a subgroup of order $25$?*

Is it correct to just use Lagrange's Theorem and state that $25$ does not divide the order of $S_{9} = 9! = 362880$?

Comment: Sure. ${}{}{}{}{}$